# Inserting screen capture into a question

Tags: support, images

Can someone please explain (or guide me to a link that explains) how to insert a screen capture, or any other image on my computer, into a question? I saw the link on inserting images, but I didn't understand the "url" part since its not applicable?

Thanks

Comment: From the [MSO FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/214632). (The images are a bit out-of-date (amusingly), but the basic idea is still the same.)

Comment: Thank you, thats what I was looking for!

Comment: Be sure to *crop* and to add a full description if possible (which will become the alt text).